# How to get checkbox value using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I ve got a form consisits of two inputs (emain, password) and one checkbox. Code is here:

```
<Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
  <TextField
    margin="normal"
    required
    fullWidth
    id="email"
    label="Email adress"
    name="email"
    autoComplete="email"
    autoFocus
  />
  <TextField
    margin="normal"
    required
    fullWidth
    name="password"
    label="Password"
    type="password"
    id="password"
    autoComplete="current-password"
  />
  <FormControlLabel
    control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
    label="Remember me"
  />
  <Button
    type="submit"
    fullWidth
    variant="contained"
    sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
  >
    Sign in
  </Button>
</Box>
```

To get the values of Email and Password I use smth.like:

```
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    console.log({
      email: data.get('email'),
      password: data.get('password'),
    });
  };
```

But what's the best practice to get the value of checkbox "Remember me" (*in FormControlLabel*)? Of course, I can make a new function to handle the changes of checkbox like:

```
<FormControlLabel
 control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
 onChanges = {newFunction}
 label="Remember me"
/>
```

But I think that's it's not a good idea, because I don't need to get all the changes of this checkbox, I just need to know the value of this checkbox in the moment of submitting the form.

Comment: Add a `name` to the checkbox, that way it should be part of the formdata.

Comment: I've added *name='remember'* to FormControl jsx-tag.  And I've added *checkbox: data.get('remember')* in handleSubmit. Is it a kind of good practice?

Comment: Sure, why not? Although I always prefer controlled inputs, where each value has a corresponding state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, you can make the checkbox controlled with a React state, but it's not needed if you are inside a form, since the form owns the info of each input element inside of it, but in order to do that you must set a `name` attribute on each input element, then you can read the values by instantiating a FormData:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       const formData = new FormData(e.target);
       const data = formData.entries();
       for (const entry of data) console.log(entry);
  };
```

A working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ictfjr

Comment: Thank you! I've added name and now if the checkbox is selected, I've got entry, if no there's just no enry

Answer (score 1):

You should use Usestate hooks

Handling a multiple CheckBox : [Link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-work-with-multiple-checkboxes-in-react/)

```
      import React, {useState} from 'react'
        
        export default () => {
            const [fName, setfName] = useState('');
            const [lName, setlName] = useState('');
            const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
            const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
            const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
    
            const handleOnChange = () => {
               setIsChecked(!isChecked);
      };
        
        const submitValue = () => {
            const frmdetails = {
                'First Name' : fName,
                'Last Name' : lName,
                'Phone' : phone,
                'Email' : email
            }
            console.log(frmdetails);
        }
        
        return(
            <>
            <hr/>
 <div className="topping">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="topping"
          name="topping"
          value="Paneer"
          checked={isChecked}
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
        Paneer
      </div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" onChange={e => setfName(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" onChange={e => setlName(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" onChange={e => setPhone(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={submitValue}>Submit</button>
            </>
            )
        }
```